# Ruby on Rails collection_select display attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails and am working with the `collection_select` method.

I have two fields I'd like to display in my select box:

`first_name` and `last_name`

So far, I can only display one or the other, not both.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
collection_select(:hour,:shopper_id,@shoppers,:id,"last_name")
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add `full_name` method to `shopper` model:

```
class Shopper < ActiveRecord::Base
  #.....
  # add this
  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

And modify the `collection_select` statement:

```
collection_select(:hour,:shopper_id,@shoppers,:id,:full_name)
```

This is because most of Rails helpers takes methods names as params, so does [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001625), which takes a `text_method` param, which is the name of the method to be called to generate the text of the option itself, thus we define `full_name` method and we pass it's name to `collection_select`.